# sql server select from two tables where colums don't equal

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm VERY new to sql so please bear with me. I have two tables named `datamig1` and `vascuproimagefile`. I want to compare `datamig1.imagefile` to `vascuproimagefile.imagefile` and `vascuproimagefile.thumbnail` and return restults that `<>` eachother. I was able to run this query for where they = each other and it worked perfect why can't it work for <>

```
select * from datamig1, vascuproimagefile where datamig1.ImageFile = vascuproimagefile.ImageFile;
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help.

Comment: For example this is the type of data that is in the columns "00000AD0-15BB-489B-8935-4FB7FC14C50F" if this file name which is currently in datamig1.imagefile is not in vascuproimagefile.imagefile or in vascuproimagefile.thumbnail I want a list of those file names.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple different ways to do this.  One is to use an `outer join / null` check:

```
select d.imagefile
from datamig1 d
   left join vascuproimagefile v on d.imagefile in (v.ImageFile, v.thumbnail)
where v.imagefile is null and v.thumbnail is null
```

---

Or you could use `not exists`:

```
select imagefile
from datamig1 d
where not exists (
    select 1
    from vascuproimagefile v
    where d.imagefile = v.imagefile or d.imagefile = v.thumbnail 
)
```